# Кто может помочь понять код в С

Tags: c

Мой друг дал мне код одной проги, но я никак не могу понять как код работает... Я знаю что она делает, НО не знаю как...
Вот код:

```
int match(char *s1, char *s2) {
    if (*s1 != '\0' && *s2 == '*')
        return (match(s1 + 1, s2) || match(s1, s2 + 1));
}
```

Можете объяснить пошагово как работает?

Comment: а вопрос то в чём?

Comment: Объясните алгоритм, хочу понять как работает

Comment: Сам не особо въехал но могу сказать что это рекурсивная функция которая возвратит один только тогда когда `*s1  *s2` будут равны `'\0'`

Comment: @AndrewRomanenko не совсем.

Comment: это простейший алгоритм проверки регулярки только с символами * и всё. При этом неэффективный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int match(char *s1, char *s2)
{
  if (!*s1 && !*s2)               //обе строки кончились
     return 1;
  if (*s1 && *s2 == '*')
     return match(s1 + 1, s2) ||  //левый на *
            match(s1, s2 + 1);    // конец *
  if (*s2 == '*')
     return match(s1, s2 + 1);    // конец *
  if (*s1 == *s2)                  // одинаковые символы 
     return match(s1 + 1, s2 + 1); //оба пропускаем
  return 0;                       //не совпало 
}

int nmatch(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    if (!*s1 && !*s2)                     //обе строки кончились
        return 1;
    if (*s1 == '*' && *s2 == '*')
        return nmatch(s1 + 1, s2);       //звёздочка на левую строку? ошибка?
    if (*s1 == *s2)            
        return nmatch(s1 + 1, s2 + 1);  // одинаковые символы
    if (*s2 == '*' && !*s1)
        return nmatch(s1, s2 + 1);      // конец *
    if (*s2 == '*')
        return nmatch(s1 + 1, s2)      //левый на *
               +                       // считаем количество вариантов? 
               nmatch(s1, s2 + 1);     // конец * 
    return 0;
}
```

Это простейший алгоритм проверки регулярки, в которой шаблон содержит только символы и `*`. Во 2 варианте учтено что 1 строка может содержать *. Но если вы считаете число способов то надо делать по аналогии с вариантом с суммой.

ВАЖНО алгоритм крайне медленный. Тест:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
******************b
```